# Need to send asynchronous url request using php and know, the time required

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous

I have a database in the cloud, i need to know, at what time and the number of requests will the server crashes down, so I have thought  of sending asynchronous requests using php and then find the time needed for serving each of it. I am bit confused as in how to proceed, I am not sure, if cURL will be useful here. Just a layout of how to proceed will be helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you trying to test how much load your database can handle? Then probably using PHP is not the best tool for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://yourserver.com/
```

-n  number of requests
-c  concurrency

There other tools to benchmark server

ab is a part of apache tools

Comment: Yeah , it helped thanks , but 
'$ ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://cloud.3owl.com/api/sample.php?usn=102
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking cloud.3owl.com (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 282 requests completed'

Comment: Not sure what is the problem? Looks like standard output by ab

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/146605/understanding-this-error-apr-socket-recv-connection-reset-by-peer-104 , this link says its some problem with the web server , how do i over come ?

Comment: Reduce am mount of concurrent connections 10 not 100

Comment: But the problem is , for 1000 requests, irrespective of the concurrent connections, it gives, apr_socket_recv.

Comment: So start from  -n 100 -c 1 and work your way up it'll give you idea ho many connections and requests server can handle

Answer (score 0):

Use [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) or [Apache benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) tool to load test your server by calling single or multiple urls, you can increase concurrency, volume of the requests to the server. siege will give you detail report of the requests and concurrency and how is your server performing, you even call your single server from multiple other servers.

Comment: Great tool..!! , but '$ ab -n 1000 -c 100 cloud.3owl.com/api/sample.php?usn=102 This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $> Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, zeustech.net Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, apache.org Benchmarking cloud.3owl.com (be patient) Completed 100 requests Completed 200 requests apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104) Total of 282 requests completed' 

Is there anyway to overcome this?

Comment: what problem you want to overcome?

Comment: I want to send 1000 request with 100 as concurrent sets , but only some portion of the 1000 request is getting completed , so how do i complete all the requests,

Comment: it should not happen, if you have sen -n 1000 then all 1000 requests should hit the server, have you tred Siege?  if you think I have given the right answer please accept the answer.

Comment: No haven't tried Siege, will try that , Thanks , it surely helped :)

Answer (score 0):

It means that server is heavly loaded with the request i.e, all the threads are busy serving the request. 
Solution : either increase the maxThread attribute count for connector in server.xml file or increase acceptCount attribute value.

acceptcount : The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.